# Set the limit on selection of a year in DatePickerDialog in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, datepickerdialog

I am new to Xamarin.android..Here in my project I am using DatePickerDialog in xamarin.android. i want to set the limit to the selection of the year. i mean i have to set the age limit as 21 years for dob. so the user is not allowed to select age beyond 21 yrs from the current date..i.e, if the current year is 2017, the user should not be allowed to select beyond 1996..how to achieve this one..?if the user select the year beyond 1996 it should again come back to 1996..

On click of a edittext, i am calling the DatePickerFragment class.
so here is code i have used.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MobileApplication.Droid
{
    public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment,
                                  DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        // TAG can be any string of your choice.
        public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

        // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
        Action<string> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

        public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<string> onDateSelected)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
            frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
            return frag;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           currently.Year - 21,
                                                           currently.Month,
                                                           currently.Day);
             dialog.DatePicker.MaxDateTime.DayOfYear.Equals(currently.Year - 21);
            return dialog;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
            //DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
            string selectedDate = (monthOfYear + 1).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + (dayOfMonth).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + year.ToString();

            //Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
            Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate);
            _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

on click of edittext, the year will set to (current year - 21). but the user is not restricted to select beyond that year..how to achieve this one..

Comment: you have to set an age limit of 21.  please, clarify people of 21 years and above can register or only people with 21 can register.

Comment: yes that i can do..but i want to restrict the selection itself..

Comment: the datepicker should not be allowed to select beyond 21 years..

Comment: dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = (long) DateTime.Now.AddYears(21)
                .ToUniversalTime()
                .Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969))
                .TotalMilliseconds;

Comment: what is 1969..?

Comment: @Dinesh kumar by using the above code..it will set the dialog to current year - 21..but it is not restricted to select beyond 21yrs..

Comment: I hope you understand how calculations are done for datetime -> long since you posted an answer, i would leave it to you " what is 1969". i hope you saw datepicker mindate | maxdate xml comments.

Comment: ya i got to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, delegate { }, currently.Year -21, currently.Month-1, currently.Day);

            dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = (long)DateTime.Now.AddYears(-21)
                .ToUniversalTime()
                .Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969))
                .TotalMilliseconds;
            dialog.Show();
```

Comment: it works well..but with one change..`DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.Activity, this, currently.Year - 21, currently.Month - 1, currently.Day);`..thank u..!!!

Answer (score 0):

So, According to this **[Link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/89379/#Comment_89379)** , by doing some minor changes the date picker is working fine. I mean now the user is not allowed to select beyond 21yrs.

So these are changes i made to my previous code..

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           currently.Year - 21,
                                                           currently.Month,
                                                           currently.Day);

            dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = new Java.Util.Date().Time - 662300000000; // 662300000000 => 1 year is converted to milliseconds..
            return dialog;
        }
```